# When link clicked add link value into url after another link has been clicked

Tags: php, html

When clicking link-1 or link-2 a modal will come up (they use the same modal) with link-a and link-b.

[image]

[image]

When link-a is clicked I need it to be `<a herf="/link-1/link-a/">link-a</a>`
So when that is clicked the url path will be as below

www.example.co.uk/link-1/link-a/

This is what I have so far;

```
<?php 
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$add = 'link-1'; 
$final = $add;
?>

<a href="/<?php echo $final;?>/link-a">link-a</a>
```

Comment: So as I understand, you want the final link, Link A to get the previous link that was clicked which would be Link 1 or Link 2 and add it into the url path ?

Comment: Correct. 
If you click link-a after clicking link-1 the path should be:                               

`<a href="/link-1/link-a/">link-a</a>`

Comment: Possibly try onClick getElementById, then output that value of the link clicked into the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do it like this

```
<?php 
 $current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
 $add = 'link-1'; 
 $final = $current_url.'/'.$add;
?>

<a href="<?php echo $final;?>/link-a">link-a</a>
```

Comment: You always add the link-1 to the end like: `link-1/link-a/link-1`

Answer (score 0):

Can you just pass the link-1 / link-2 url as a parameter for your modal?

Something like this:

```
//button for modal
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" data-url="www.example.co.uk/link-1">Link 1</button>

//passing url to modal
 var url = button.data('url')
 var modal = $(this)
 modal.find('.modal-body').html("<a href='" + url + "'/link-a' >Link-a</a>")
```

[modal doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)